# Where can I download Windows 7 gadgets

Tags: windows-7, desktop-gadget

I like Windows 7's gadgets, and have just noticed you can no longer download them by clicking [Get more gadgets online](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-GB/windows/downloads/personalize/gadgets) in the **Gadgets** window.

Are they still available online somewhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not all in one place like it was before.

http://addgadgets.com/ has All CPU Meter, Network Meter, Digital Clock, GPU Meter, Battery Meter, Drives Meter, Earthquakes Meter and a few others.

http://www.thoosje.com/Windows-7-gadgets-gallery.html has a lot.